# Flutter Layout with Squares Only inside Variable-Height Containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to try and create a layout of variable-height, but will take up the full width of the screen. I want 2 big squares on the left, with 2 little squares on the right of the squares as needed for each big square on the left. See the purple picture for details.

However, I can't seem to be able to do this where I guarantee the inner widgets and components will be squares. Is there a way to achieve this?

If this is possible, is it possible for me to also achieve the ability to drag and rearrange (scaling as I rotate the squares back and forth as well too)? I'm trying to achieve that type of layout and the ability to rotate from each one of the 6 pictures and it will scale correctly as needed in that aspect (or the ability to drag and drop to rearrange each of the pictures).

Help would be greatly appreciated! I showed what I did below, but it doesn't seem to work to even have square items inside of the variable-height container.

[image: A Layout where the height is variable, but everything inside should be squared (one big square, with 2 small ones half its size on its right)]

```
return Container(
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1.0,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            flex: 7,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Above code has resulted in the actual items being non-squared]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. You should start from here. It is responsive, you just need to work more on the alignment when the screen is too small

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 12.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 7,
                      child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Expanded(
                            child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 7,
                      child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          Expanded(
                            child: _buildSquare(Colors.purple),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSquare(Color color) {
    return Center(
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually tried the above, but it seems it won't fit what I'm trying to do which is the following:
1) 2 Big squares on the left side
2) Each big square is accompanied by 2 equal smaller squares on its right.

I tried the above, and it seems that it won't be able to layout correctly in that sense as it is not possible to make the squares follow that pattern.